# how passing ng-bind values in to a variable at asp.net core view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ng-bind-html

I have a tag like this :
`<a data-ng-click="showform(@item.CategoryId)">`

I have a  variable "catid" in razor...
`@{int catid; }`

I want save value in 'catid'

this my js code :

```
       
        app.controller('Result', function ($scope) {           
            $scope.CatId = 0;
            $scope.showform = function (id) {
                $scope.CatId = id;    
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can not set server side variable using client side js code. Can you clarify more about the actual scenario/requirement?

Comment: i want to use CatId for a linq code and show category name at view

Comment: Why not make request from angularjs client side to a backend action with `CatId` as parameter and query data with linq, then update category name in UI based on received data on angularjs client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to use CatId for a linq code and show category name at view

> Can you give me a sample code?

Following is a working example, you can refer to it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Result">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <a data-ng-click="showform(@item.CategoryId)">CategoryId is @item.CategoryId</a>
        <br />
    }
    <h2>Name of selected Category is {{CatName}}</h2>
</div>
```

*Make request(s) using AngularJS $http service*

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('Result', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.CatId = 0;
        $scope.CatName = "";

        $scope.showform = function (id) {
            $scope.CatId = id;

            $http.get("/GetCategoryNameById?catid=" + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.CatName = response.data;
                    //your code logic here based on your actual requirement
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

*My `GetCategoryNameById` action method for testing purpose*

```
[HttpGet("GetCategoryNameById")]
public IActionResult GetCategoryNameById(int catid)
{
    //your code logic here

    //query data based on received catid

    var category = _dbcontext.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == catid).FirstOrDefault();

    return Ok($"{category.CategoryName}");
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: thanks bro if I want to send Two different values in return how can to do?
`return Ok($"{category}",$"{field}");`

Comment: `field` is Data List

Comment: You can define a viewmodel class with expected properties for category and  field etc, then return it to client app.

Comment: ok I don't know how to get the Model in this code?

` $http.get("/GetCategoryNameById?catid=" + id)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.Fields = response.data;

            }); `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this way.

```
<input type="hidden" name="catid" id="catid" value="{{Catid}}" />
```

When you submit form this value passed to asp.net core.